# In the semi linear uniform space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convergence-divergence, continuity, uniform-spaces

In the semi linear uniform space, If  $f$ is a function from $(X ,Γ_X)$ to ($Y,Γ_Y)$ where $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$ whenever $x_n$ converges to $x$,show that $f$ is continuous at $x$.

Comment: Do you mean both uniformities $\Gamma_X$ and $\Gamma_Y$ are linear (=a chain)? Is $x_n$ a sequence?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be not continuous at $x$. There is some net $(d_t)_{t\in T}$ with $d_t \to x$ and $f(d_t)\not\to f(x)$. So we can assume there some net $(U_t)_{t\in T}$ of neighborhoods with
$$(\forall t\in T)(f(t)\notin U_t)$$

As $\{U_t\mid t\in T\}$ is a chain, there must be a strictly decreasing sequence ${U_{t_n}}$ such that
$$(\forall n)(f(t_n)\notin U_{t_n})$$
But then by assumption, $d_{t_n}\not\to x$. A contradiction.

Comment: Yes both uniformities are chains,and xn is asequence. Your proof is true if you talk about afirst countable tpological space.Now if you assume that your space is afirst countable,then you can construct asequence of open sets whose intersection is asinglton x(i.e the sequence is convergent) but the image of each term does not.

Comment: @eman: Because $\{U_t\mid t\in T\}$ is a chain a decreasing sequence can be extracted no matter first countable or not.